# How can a Dart application read cell data from google spreadsheets

Tags: google-docs, gdata, google-docs-api, dart

What are the possible options and setups one would need for reading data out of a google docs spreadsheet into a dart web application? Does dart need the wrapper around gdata REST api to do this? Has any dart project or sample interacted with google docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer Google APIs have a common API infrastructure where the client libraries are always up to date. There is such a client library for Dart (http://docs.google-api-dart-client.googlecode.com/git/index.html).

However, it looks like Google Spreadsheets is still using an older API infrastructure called GData. There is no GData client library for Dart that I know of.

Hence, I think the most sensible thing to do is to make raw HTTP calls. I'm not sure if you're trying to do this on the client or the server. If you're trying to do it on the client, you're going to have to make sure Google Spreadsheets supports CORS.

If you happen to be using a different programming language on the server, there is like a GData client library for that language. See (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#setting_up_your_client_library).