# Is it possible to read a Google Spreadsheet from (server-VM-run) Dart code?

Tags: dart, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'd like to read data from a Google Drive Spreadsheet in Dart code (running as a console app in the VM, not in the browser). I'm somewhat confused by the names of the API; Sheets is part of Google Drive, but all the Google Drive API docs I can find relate to integrating the UI of Drive into your app.

There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065071/how-can-a-dart-application-read-cell-data-from-google-spreadsheets) question on SO, but it's over 2 years so I'm hoping that it's no longer correct, and there is an API.

I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dart-client/) Dart Google API library, but it says:

> THIS LIBRARY IS DEPRECATED
>   Please use the Google API Dart libraries in http://pub.dartlang.org, the Dart package manager
>   Search for 'google' or the API of your choice. For example:
>   http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_drive_v2_api

However I'm struggling to find which package I'm supposed to use. The Drive API one doesn't have a lot of info, and there doesn't appear to be one with "Sheets" or "Docs" in the name.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the Spreadsheet API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/.

There isn't a Dart lib for it, but it's a well formed REST API so very easy to program against.

Answer (score 1):

Sheets is not exactly part of Google Drive, it is part of the Google Docs productivity suite that is stored in Google Drive.  Google Drive is the general cloud storage layer.  The Drive API is for interacting with files of all types that are stored in Drive.  You can interact with Sheets files using that API to modify metadata or import or export to/from other formats like csvs.  That is possible to do from Dart (I'm not sure if there is a Dart-specific client library, but this API is just rest calls so its always possible.)

If you want to interact with a Sheet at a lower level to do things like modify a single cell, you can use [AppScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), however that cannot be done from Dart.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for Google APIs support generators that create access libraries for every language.
For example https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_drive_v2_api.

You can generate them yourself (also for your own endpoints) using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/discovery_api_client_generator but for most APIs there are packages already in pub.dartlang.org.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question - what library should I use for Sheets? If it's google_drive_v2_api, where in the docs should I be looking for a function to read from a Sheet?

Comment: I haven't used it myself yet. Maybe someone else has more detailed information.

Comment: I have successfully used these packages with a few APIs but not drive.